# Qt App causes Segmentation Fault upon GLWidget.show();

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

When I step through the debugger, I get the following pop-up message:

```
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the Operating System.

Signal name : 
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : 
Segmentation fault
```

Which is dependent (I think) on these lines of code:

```
#ifndef Q_WS_WINCE
    inline void show() { setVisible(true); }
#else
    void show();
#endif
    inline void hide() { setVisible(false); }
    inline QT_MOC_COMPAT void setShown(bool shown) { setVisible(shown); }
```

As far as I know, `Q_WS_WINCE` is NOT defined, although I haven't been able to find the definition behind it via Google; [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qtglobal.html#Q_WS_WIN) is the closest I've been able to find, although it lacks a `CE` definition.

According to my debugger, this is what is being called, as the arrow follows `#ifndef Q_WS_WINCE`, at the call of the `inline void show() { setVisible(true); }` function.

I am at a loss as to how this could be happening; what is happening here? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10, along with Qt Creator as my IDE. I should also note that this JUST started happening a few minutes ago; I was able to step through most of my code before without any issues.

**GLWidget Header File**

```
#pragma once

#include <QGLWidget>
#include <QInputEvent>
#include "Cube.h"

class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit GLWidget( QWidget *parent = 0 );

    ~GLWidget( void );

    QSize minimumSizeHint( void ) const;

    QSize sizeHint( void ) const;

public slots:
    void SetXRotation( int angle );

    void SetYRotation( int angle );

    void SetZRotation( int angle );

signals:
    void xRotationChanged( int angle );

    void yRotationChanged( int angle );

    void zRotationChanged( int angle );

protected:
    void initializeGL( void );

    void paintGL( void );

    void resizeGL( int width, int height );

    void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent *event );

    void mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *event );

private:
    Cube *mCube;

    int mXRot;

    int mYRot;

    int mZRot;

    QPoint mLastPos;

    QColor mQtGreen;

    QColor mQtPurple;

};
```

**GLWidget Source File**

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include <QtGui>
#include <QtOpenGL>

#include <qmath.h>
#include <QMatrix4x4>

#include "GLWidget.h"

#ifndef GL_MULTISAMPLE
#define GL_MULTISAMPLE 0x809D
#endif

static void qNormalizeAngle( int &angle )
{
    const int ANGLE_MULTIPLIER = 360 * 16;

    while( angle < 0 )
        angle += ANGLE_MULTIPLIER;
    while ( angle > ANGLE_MULTIPLIER )
        angle -= ANGLE_MULTIPLIER;
}

GLWidget::GLWidget( QWidget *parent ) :
    QGLWidget( parent ),
    mXRot( 0 ),
    mYRot( 0 ),
    mZRot( 0 )
{    
}

GLWidget::~GLWidget( void )
{
    delete mCube;
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL( void )
{
    mQtGreen = QColor::fromCmyk( 0.40, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    mQtPurple = QColor::fromCmyk( 0.39, 0.39, 0.0, 0.0 );

    //glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH );

    qglClearColor( mQtPurple );

    mCube = new Cube( this );
    mCube->Init();
    mCube->SetColor( mQtGreen.dark() );

    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
    glEnable( GL_CULL_FACE );
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
    glEnable( GL_MULTISAMPLE );
    static GLfloat lightPosition[4] = { 0.5, 5.0, 7.0, 1.0 };
    glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPosition );
}

QSize GLWidget::minimumSizeHint( void ) const
{
    return QSize( 50, 50 );
}

void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent *event )
{
    mLastPos = event->pos();
}

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent *event )
{
    static const int ANGLE_ADDIFIER = 8;

    int dx = event->x() - mLastPos.x();
    int dy = event->y() - mLastPos.y();

    if ( event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton )
    {
        SetXRotation( ( mXRot + ANGLE_ADDIFIER ) * dy );
        SetYRotation( ( mYRot + ANGLE_ADDIFIER ) * dx );

        qDebug() << "You pressed the left mouse button!" << '\n';
    }
    else if ( event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton )
    {
        SetXRotation( ( mXRot + ANGLE_ADDIFIER ) * dy );
        SetZRotation( ( mZRot + ANGLE_ADDIFIER ) * dx );

        qDebug() << "You pressed the right mouse button!" << '\n';
    }

    mLastPos = event->pos();
}

void GLWidget::paintGL( void )
{
    static const GLfloat ANGLE_DIVISOR = 16.0;

    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, -10.0 );

    glRotatef( mXRot / ANGLE_DIVISOR, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( mYRot / ANGLE_DIVISOR, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( mZRot / ANGLE_DIVISOR, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );

    mCube->Draw();
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL( int width, int height )
{
    int side = qMin( width, height );

    //glutInitWindowPosition( 0, 0 );
    //glutInitWindowSize( width, height );

    glViewport( ( width - side ) / VIEWPORT_DIVISOR, ( height - side ) / VIEWPORT_DIVISOR, side, side );
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();

#ifdef QT_OPENGL_ES_1
    glOrthof( -0.5, +0.5, -0.5, +0.5, 4.0, 15.0 );
#else
    glOrtho( -0.5, +0.5, -0.5, +0.5, 4.0, 15.0 );
#endif*/

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
}

void GLWidget::SetXRotation( int angle )
{
    qNormalizeAngle( angle );

    if ( angle != mYRot )
    {
        mYRot = angle;
        emit yRotationChanged( angle );
        updateGL();
    }
}

void GLWidget::SetYRotation( int angle )
{
    qNormalizeAngle( angle );

    if ( angle != mXRot )
    {
        mXRot = angle;
        emit xRotationChanged( angle );
        updateGL();
    }
}

void GLWidget::SetZRotation( int angle )
{
    qNormalizeAngle( angle );

    if ( angle != mZRot )
    {
        mZRot = angle;
        emit zRotationChanged( angle );
        updateGL();
    }
}

QSize GLWidget::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize( 400, 400 );
}
```

Comment: What is the call stack when application segfaults?

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit: I had an `mCube->Init();` function call which was misplaced somewhere in the code. This should now be considered solved.